# Is the smooth function on Euclidean space still smooth on Riemannian manifold? or for embedd manifold in Euclidean space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

If there have L-smooth function f(x) on Euclidean space, whether smoothness remain on Riemannian manifold, or embedding manifold on Euclidean space? if remain, what is connection between smooth parameter L ?